# Get nonce from Square

Tags: javascript, square

I'm building a website. In this website, I need to process credit card payments via [Square](https://squareup.com/). My designers have an interesting UI that I want to use. For that reason, the [Square Payment Form](https://docs.connect.squareup.com/articles/adding-payment-form) mentioned in the docs is too limiting for me. Yet, in order to process payments, I need to still get a nonce from Square.

My question is, is there a way to retrieve a nonce from Square without using the `SqPaymentForm`? If so, how? I don't see any documentation for this. However, the `SqPaymentForm` is just in a client-side JavaScript library so there should be a way to do it. But, that library is all obfuscated on the client and I don't see the code on the [Square GitHub page](https://github.com/square). I'm hoping I'm just overlooking something.

Is there a way to get a nonce from Square programmatically?

Thank you!

Comment: from a UX/monetization perspective: checkout is NOT the time for "interesting UI". be afraid. very afraid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The nonce seems to come from a postMessage to an iframe on `https://connect.squareup.com`

Code from `https://js.squareup.com/v2/paymentform` :

```
(r.prototype.requestCardNonceIfValidForm = function() {
  this.sendIframeMessage({
    eventName: 'requestCardNonceIfValidForm'
  });
}),
...
(r.prototype.sendIframeMessage = function(e) {
  var t = this.env.serviceUrl();
  this.iframeControllers.cardNumber.element.contentWindow.postMessage(e, t);
}),
...
service: 'https://connect.squareup.com'
```

Answer (score 0):

No, there is not a way to get a card nonce programmatically, you must use the payment form.